# how to sum values of some map keys in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a map of items and its prices, I want to sum some selected(not all) values of keys
how? in dart
I have tried all values except one but cant do other than this.
my map contains  string key and  double  value

Comment: Can you share some code? Maybe some of the things you've tried?

Comment: It is necessary to provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and include what do you expect from your code and what went wrong. It is not clear about your *selected(not all) values of keys*

Answer (score 1):

In general, you want to perform a `filter-map-reduce` operation here - `filter` to get all elements which have a certain property, `map` to extract the value from each element, and finally `reduce` to aggregate the results to a single value (the sum, in this case).

An example in Dart could look something like this:

```
  final Map<String, int> map = {
    "item": 10,
    "anotherItem": 20,
    "yetAnotherItem": 30
  };
  final sumOfEvenLengthKeys = map.entries
      .where((e) => e.key.length % 2 == 0)
      .map((e) => e.value)
      .reduce((a, b) => a + b);
```

Which would produce `40`.

Comment: That can all be done in one step, actually, with something like `map.entries.fold(0, (prev, e) => e.key.length % 2 == 0 ? prev + e.value : prev)`

Comment: Definitely - there are many ways to achieve this result. Many iterable method chains can often be replaced by a single `fold` or `reduce`, it's just a different way.